# Как задать цвет тексту между тегами html циклом php

Tags: php, css

Всем здравствуйте.Я начинающий программист и пока все не просто дается. Нужно решить такую задачу. Дана переменная с текстом. В ней теги, которые задают наклонный текст. <em> и <i>. Как выделить красным цветом то, что находится между этими тегами? Как это сделать если искать номер позиции тегов я знаю. Но это очень длинный код. А как это сделать циклом? Чтобы если текст меняется, то все равно все, что между этими тегами остается красным? Но как... Не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста.Вот пример текста.

$x = 'Некоторые ученые считают, что <em>сновидения,</em> вероятно, являются выделением<i> нейронами ненужного </i>материала — своего рода чисткой. Если это так, то почему так называемый ментальный мусор имеет обратную связь через<em> память и может восстанавливаться? </em>Клетки мозга все-таки умнее.
Сны заслуживают<i>нашего внимания, иначе мы не могли бы </i>запоминать их.
Все имеет под собой какую-то основу.<em> Если предположить, что мы видим сны-предсказания или сны, </em>решающие проблемы, <i>какой может быть их цель?</i>
Высшим приоритетом наших нервных клеток является обеспечение выживания отдельного человека и человеческой расы в целом. Если вы посмотрите на сны с этой точки зрения, то можете сорвать<em> большой куш. Ваши нейроны </em>посредством механизма сновидений <i>могут служить для вас зеркалом, говорящим: </i>"Посмотри на себя, как ты реагируешь. Это же стресс. <em>Ты вредишь себе, укорачиваешь свою жизнь. </em>Тебе необходимо изменить поведение".
Вот почему следует обращать <i>внимание на сны. Что они в действительности означают,</i> пытаясь предостеречь вас от попадания в <em>возможную стрессовую ситуацию? Иногда полезно предположить, что всякий человек из вашего сна</em> является отражением одной из граней вас самого.
Сосед, брат, отец, собака <i>— не могут ли они быть воплощением вашего добрососедства,</i> вашей братской, отцовской или животной натуры? <em>Подумайте, какие ваши стороны нуждаются в более позитивном контроле.</em>';

Comment: Это делается на клиенте с помощью css.

Answer (score 0):

Задать этим элементам атрибут class и описать класс в CSS.
В вашем файле CSS пропишите:

```
.red_text_em_i{
    color: red;
}
```

Ваша переменная будем выглядить так:

```
$x = 'Некоторые ученые считают, что <em class="red_text_em_i">сновидения,</em> вероятно, являются выделением<i class="red_text_em_i"> нейронами ненужного </i>материала ...';
```

Или можно обернуть в div или p. Прописав им id, и описав CSS так:

```
#block-1 i, #block-1 em{
    color: red;
}
```

Ваша переменная:

```
 $x = '<div id="block-1">Некоторые ученые считают, что <em>сновидения,</em> вероятно, являются выделением<i> нейронами ненужного </i>материала ...</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Вставь просто в код, не нужно никакие классы добавлять

```
 <style>
 em, i {
 color: red;
 }
 </style>
```

```html
Некоторые ученые считают, что <em>сновидения,</em> вероятно, являются выделением<i> нейронами ненужного </i>материала — своего рода чисткой. Если это так, то почему так называемый ментальный мусор имеет обратную связь через<em> память и может восстанавливаться? </em>Клетки мозга все-таки умнее. Сны заслуживают<i>нашего внимания, иначе мы не могли бы </i>запоминать их. Все имеет под собой какую-то основу.<em> Если предположить, что мы видим сны-предсказания или сны, </em>решающие проблемы, <i>какой может быть их цель?</i> Высшим приоритетом наших нервных клеток является обеспечение выживания отдельного человека и человеческой расы в целом. Если вы посмотрите на сны с этой точки зрения, то можете сорвать<em> большой куш. Ваши нейроны </em>посредством механизма сновидений <i>могут служить для вас зеркалом, говорящим: </i>"Посмотри на себя, как ты реагируешь. Это же стресс. <em>Ты вредишь себе, укорачиваешь свою жизнь. </em>Тебе необходимо изменить поведение". Вот почему следует обращать <i>внимание на сны. Что они в действительности означают,</i> пытаясь предостеречь вас от попадания в <em>возможную стрессовую ситуацию? Иногда полезно предположить, что всякий человек из вашего сна</em> является отражением одной из граней вас самого. Сосед, брат, отец, собака <i>— не могут ли они быть воплощением вашего добрососедства,</i> вашей братской, отцовской или животной натуры? <em>Подумайте, какие ваши стороны нуждаются в более позитивном контроле.</em>
    <style>
     em, i {
     color: red;
     }
     </style>
```

в php будет так:

```
$x = '<style>em, i {color: red;}</style>'.$text;
echo $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

**olisiia**, ну так-то тут одной строкой можно решить:

```
$x = 'Некоторые ученые считают, что <em>сновидения,</em> вероятно, являются выделением<i> нейронами ненужного </i>материала — своего рода чисткой. Если это так, то почему так называемый ментальный мусор имеет обратную связь через<em> память и может восстанавливаться? </em>Клетки мозга все-таки умнее.
Сны заслуживают<i>нашего внимания, иначе мы не могли бы </i>запоминать их.
Все имеет под собой какую-то основу.<em> Если предположить, что мы видим сны-предсказания или сны, </em>решающие проблемы, <i>какой может быть их цель?</i>
Высшим приоритетом наших нервных клеток является обеспечение выживания отдельного человека и человеческой расы в целом. Если вы посмотрите на сны с этой точки зрения, то можете сорвать<em> большой куш. Ваши нейроны </em>посредством механизма сновидений <i>могут служить для вас зеркалом, говорящим: </i>"Посмотри на себя, как ты реагируешь. Это же стресс. <em>Ты вредишь себе, укорачиваешь свою жизнь. </em>Тебе необходимо изменить поведение".
Вот почему следует обращать <i>внимание на сны. Что они в действительности означают,</i> пытаясь предостеречь вас от попадания в <em>возможную стрессовую ситуацию? Иногда полезно предположить, что всякий человек из вашего сна</em> является отражением одной из граней вас самого.
Сосед, брат, отец, собака <i>— не могут ли они быть воплощением вашего добрососедства,</i> вашей братской, отцовской или животной натуры? <em>Подумайте, какие ваши стороны нуждаются в более позитивном контроле.</em>';

echo preg_replace('~(<(em|i)>)(.+?)(</\2>)~', '$1<span style="color:red">$3</span>$4', $x);
```